# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'fp'

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error when i try to send a txt file to a discord webhook. (python3)

```
import os
import subprocess
import requests
import discord
import dhooks
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed

hook = Webhook("hook")
Discord_txt = open("data.txt", "r+")
hook.send(file=Discord_txt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://pypi.org/project/dhooks/), you should be using the `File` class from `dhooks`:

```py
from dhooks import Webhook, File

hook = Webhook("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/...")
Discord_txt = File("data.txt")
hook.send(file=Discord_txt)
```